# How can I detect if the clipboard is reachable in firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, clipboard

For my JavaScript project I need to detect if the clipboard is reachable. Because in Firefox you need to configure an access for every site which needs it, otherwise some functions (like the `execCommand` with cut, copy or paste attribute) can't be executed and I need to know that.

Answer (score 2):

You could try saving something into the clipboard.  If it fails, you know it is not accessible.

```
try
{
    // Use some library to save some data into the clipboard.
}
catch (ex)
{
    alert("Your browser seems to block access to the clipboard.");
}
```

Comment: Yes i could but i'm not allowed tu use any extern library to try to save data in the clipboard, i must do it in pure javascript :/

Answer (score 0):

Access to the clipboard is disallowed in Chrome and Firefox per default. With pure javascript it can't be done in other browsers than Internet Explorer. You will need a Flash-shim.

You can find an article about how to achieve that crossbrowser-compatibly [here](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/06/javascript-copy-to-clipboard.html).

A good library for this is [Zeroclipboard](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard).

Comment: I know that it is desactivate per default... But i need to detect it, because i need to warn the user that he need to configure his browser.

Comment: @BlackMario Try the library i mentioned in the answer. However, I don't know, if you can *detect* the reachability of the clipboard this way.

Comment: I can't use this library because i need to do this in pure javascript... :/

Comment: @BlackMario Other than in Internet Explorer, this can't be achieved with pure javascript.

Comment: :/ this is what i feared... :/